# PouchDB get Promise returning null for 'this'

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB with Ionic v2. And I'm facing a problem when trying to access this inside *.then* from *.get*.

```
public start(): Promise<any> {
    return this.db.get('step.current').then(function (doc) {
        Logger.log(this);
        Logger.log(doc);
        if (doc) return this.get(doc.name);
        return this.get('start.json');
    }).catch(err => {
        Logger.error(err);
        return this.get('start.json');
    });
}
```

Logger prints **null** and the **doc** object, but when trying to execute *this.get(doc.name)* it fails and enter the *.catch* where *this.get('start.json');* is working.

Am I missing something here? I don't see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
then(function (doc) {
```

by

```
then(doc => {
```

That's the whole point of arrow functions: they're automatically bound to `this`.

Comment: wow thanks, I'm embarrassed for not noticing that. I might need a rest.